# Hide option not work IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

i want to show/hide some elements in a multiselect list; my code works fine in Chrome, but I cannot figure out why it is not working in IE. Here just a simplified version of my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ID_DropDown" multiple="multiple" name="DropDown">
<option value="1">value1</option>
<option value="2">value2</option>
<option value="3">value3</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    for (var i = 0; i < ID_DropDown.options.length; i++) {
        $("#ID_DropDown option[value=" + ID_DropDown.options[i].value + "]").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Any idea? 
Really thanks

Comment: Could you disable it instead of hiding it?

Comment: It won't work in IE as well as some other browsers. Choices are disable or remove.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I can disable or hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not support the hide() function of jquery but you you can hide the elements using

Hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    for (var i = 0; i < ID_DropDown.options.length; i++) {
        $("#ID_DropDown option[value=" + ID_DropDown.options[i].value + "]").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ID_DropDown" multiple="multiple" name="DropDown">
<option value="1">value1</option>
<option value="2">value2</option>
<option value="3">value3</option>
</select>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OpZrpgAYaqfyGdcBeakc?p=preview

Comment: This method will leave blank white spaces in place of the hidden options. If you're only hiding some options in the list, it looks pretty ugly. For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/7tWNr02Uclr2WyWWEMju